# how to translate passing a listener in a java example to .net in monodroid

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, universal-image-loader

Using a monodroid java bindings project of Android Universal Image Library, how would I translate this from java to .net?  Can I pass it in a lambda for the loading listener?

The Java code example

```
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and return Bitmap to callback
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        hideSpinner();  
        //do I set the image view to the view we get back here?
    }
});
```

.NET ?

```
ImageLoader.Instance.LoadImage(imageUri, ... can I put a lambda in here or do I have to
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# does not support anonymous classes with Interface implementations, such can only implement public read-only properties. So you will have to create a class, which implements the `SimpleImageLoadingListener`.

Something in the lines of:

```
public class MySimpleImageLoadingListener : SimpleImageLoadingListener
{
    public override void OnLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage)
    {
        //Do whatever you need in here.
    }
}
```

Then you have to create an instance and pass it to `LoadImage()`:

```
ImageLoader.Instance.LoadImage(imageUri, new MySimpleImageLoadingListener());
```